# Excluding a character in a FOR loop

Tags: for-loop, batch-file, cmd, findstr, regedit

I would like to display the information regarding the ProfileImagePath value of one windows user who don't have the "_" character in his username :

```
@echo off
cls
for /f %%I in ('dir /a:d-h /b C:\Users\ ^| %SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /b /l /v "_"') do (
        FOR /F "delims=" %%k IN ('reg query "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList"^|findstr.exe /R "S-1-5-21-[0-9]*-[0-9]*-[0-9]*-[0-9]*$" 2^>nul') do (
        reg query "%%k" /v "ProfileImagePath"|findstr /i /e /c:"%%~I"
        )   
)
```

But the findstr command also takes into account users with the "_" character, while in the first FOR command, I have excluded this character  :

```
ProfileImagePath    REG_EXPAND_SZ    C:\Users\user1
ProfileImagePath    REG_EXPAND_SZ    C:\Users\_user1
```

How is it possible ? How to take this into account in the 2nd FOR command ?

Comment: There's something I don't understand about your question, which you may need to properly explain, if you want some focused assistance. Why are you jumping through hoops to determine the profile image path, when you've already began with a Command which limits those already to `C:\Users`. Surely `For /F "Delims=" %%G In ('Dir "C:\Users" /B /A:D ^| %SystemRoot%\System32\findStr.exe /B /V "_"') Do @Echo C:\Users\%%G` would get you the profile path!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`findstr /i /e /c:"user1"` searches for strings ending with `user1`. However `_user1` also ends with `user1` :(

Changing it to `findstr /i /e /c:"\%%~I"` is one way to solve your problem :)